# excel VBA For each loop for range error #VALUE

Tags: excel, vba

I have used for each loop through my defined function in excel VBA but the function output is #VALUE. I think the error is inside my loop that is as follow:

Thank you guys for comments. My function code is as follow that I have corrected the original one I sent :

```
Public Function MaxWindDir(warr As Range) As Integer
Dim WindDir() As Integer
Dim maxwindsp As Integer
Dim wcell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim MaxDir As Integer
i = 0
maxwindsp = Application.Max(warr)
For Each wcell In warr
    If wcell.Value = maxwindsp Then
        WindDir(i) = Range("J" & wcell.Row).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next wcell
If i = 1 Then
    MaxWindDir = WindDir(0)
Else
    MaxDir = WindDir(0)
    For i = 0 To UBound(WindDir)
        If WindDir(i) >= MaxDir Then
            MaxDir = WindDir(i)
        End If
    Next i
    MaxWindDir = MaxDir
End If
End Function
```

Please help me out of this error.

Comment: Best to post all of your code, it's much easier for us to get to the core of the problem

Comment: @CallumDA Normally, I would agree with you. But in this case it might very well be that this has nothing to do with the code but rather the `.Value` of the cells. If `wcell.Value` contains an error value such as `#REF!` or `#DIV/0!` or `#VALUE` then `If wcell.Value = maxwindsp Then` will fail because VBA cannot compare an error to `maxwindsp` (whatever that might be). So, the OP will have to include some error handling with something like `If IsError(wcell.Value) Then` (what should VBA do with cells that contain an error value).

Comment: In your loop `For Each wcell In warr.Cells` you are checking each `wcell` (also in your first If). However, in your second If you are switching to `cell` ?

Comment: Hard to tell if it's related to your issue or not without seeing more code, but the 2 calls to `Range` should be `warr.Range`.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have put the complete code of my function above. wcell.value is ok. there is no problem with cells value. the problem appears when I use an array inside For Each loop! because when I use a variable instead of an array the function has output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring because your `WindDir` array is undimensioned, so the lines `WindDir(i)...` will throw an error.

It's not great form to iteratively redimension an array within a loop, but the added `ReDim Preserve` line below in your code shows you what I mean:

```
For Each wcell In warr
    If wcell.Value = maxwindsp Then
        ReDim Preserve WindDir(i)
        WindDir(i) = Range("J" & wcell.Row).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next wcell
```

Your post throws up a couple of other points too:

1. Perhaps consider calling your UDFs from a module while you develop them. This way any errors will be more meaningfully displayed to you. If you run the following routine, calling your function as posted, the undimensioned array issue would be highlighted immediately:

   ```
   Public Sub RunMe()
       Dim r As Range

       Set r = Sheet1.Range("K2:K19") 'or whatever the range is
       Debug.Print MaxWindDir(r)
   End Sub
   ```
2. Why trouble yourself with the array at all? Given that you're accessing  the `WindDir` values in the first loop, why not just check for the maximum there? This way, your entire function could simply be:

   ```
   Public Function MaxWindDir(warr As Range) As Long
       Dim wcell As Range
       Dim maxWindSpd As Long
       Dim windSpd As Long
       Dim windDir As Long

       maxWindSpd = Application.Max(warr)
       For Each wcell In warr.Cells
           windSpd = wcell.Value2
           If windSpd = maxWindSpd Then
               windDir = warr.Worksheet.Cells(wcell.Row, "J").Value2
               If windDir >= MaxWindDir Then MaxWindDir = windDir
           End If
       Next

   End Function
   ```
3. Note @Comitern's point about the `Range` qualifier (and my rather clumsy attempt at keeping faithful to your posted code whilst still qualifying the range).

Comment: Thank you Ambie. A perfect answer to my question. I preferred to use your suggested code which is simpler!

Comment: No problem. If you're satisfied with the answer then please remove this from the unanswered questions by 'accepting' this answer.